# How to make UIButton background image with gradient (Swift)

Tags: swift, uibutton, gradient

[image]

Everyone please help me how to make a UIButton like this, I have searched solution before but I can not get anyone. Thanks!

Comment: You could layout a button onto of a `UIImageView` or use the `setBackgroundImage(for:)` to specify an image - maybe with a linear gradient and transparency if you want to show something below it ...

Answer (score 2):

Declare new button subclass:

```
class GradientButton : UIButton {

    var leftColor = UIColor.red
    var rightColor = UIColor.green
    var customImage : UIImage? {
        didSet {
            updateImageView()
        }
    }
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    let customImageView = UIImageView()

    override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            gradientLayer.frame = bounds
            layer.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    convenience init(leftColor: UIColor, rightColor: UIColor, image: UIImage) {
        self.init()

        self.leftColor = leftColor
        self.rightColor = rightColor
        customImage = image
        updateImageView()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        defaultInitializer()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        defaultInitializer()
    }

    func defaultInitializer() {

        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [leftColor.cgColor, rightColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 1, y: 0.5)
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
        layer.layoutIfNeeded()

        addSubview(customImageView)
        customImageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }

    func updateImageView() {
        customImageView.image = customImage
        customImageView.alpha = 0.2
        layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

And init like:

```
    let rect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 100)
    let button = GradientButton(leftColor: UIColor.red, rightColor: UIColor.cyan, image: UIImage(named: "1")!)
    button.frame = rect
    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Or even with storyboard.

Other settings as text color, font etc. you can find in UIButton declaration.
Happy coding!

Comment: If you add subView to UIbutton, that makes button can not fire event when it is tapped

Comment: If i have an outlet like `@IBOutlet var finishButton: GradientButton!` then how do we set color on it through `convenience init(leftColor: UIColor, rightColor: UIColor, image: UIImage)` ?